# Programmatically created SQL job: seconds omitted from StartDate

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm creating an SSRS subscription programmatically and forwarding it to `CreateSubscription` method with parameter `matchData` as:

```xml
<ScheduleDefinition><StartDateTime>2013-05-08T11:38:13</StartDateTime></ScheduleDefinition>
```

I see that the `Subscriptions` table stores the date correctly (with seconds), but in the `Schedule` table, in 'StartDate' column the date is "2013-05-08 11:38:00.000".

In the "Job Activity Monitor" I see that the job will start at "2013-05-08 11:38:00.000" and not at "2013-05-08 11:38:13.000".

Where did these 13 seconds go? Why was it omitted?

I'm using:

- SSRS 2008 R2 SP1
- MSSQL 2008

Comment: o.O interesting situation/question. I hope you're asking this out of curiosity?

Comment: I have a critical bug in the system :-). We migrate the system from SSRS 2008 to SSRS 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging to the process with SQL Profiler, looks like all SSRS jobs are created without seconds.
My solution is update the job with the following code:

```
DECLARE @JobTime INT = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @ScheduledExecution, 108), ':','')
```

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
SET @jobId = (SELECT job_id FROM BE_LAB_DB01.msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view WHERE name = @JobName)
EXEC BE_LAB_DB01.msdb.dbo.sp_update_jobschedule @job_id = @jobId ,@name ='Schedule_1',@active_start_time    = @JobTime